# Load an image "on the fly" in RAM, without using the hard disk

Tags: java, ram

It is possible to get a text from the internet (or even decoding a string) and represent it in a JLabel, without touching the hard disk.
So, I was wondering if it was possible to do the same with an image. Let me explain myself:
I want to represent an image with its hexadecimal representation in a JLabel "on the fly", I mean, in RAM, without even touching the hard disk. I don't mean loding it from the internet, I mean something like reading a file which has the hexadecimal code of an image, converting it to ASCII and programmatically insert it into a JLabel, like if it were a file.
Is this even possible? I think I am not being very clear, but I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: If you already have a hex string, why would you need to write it to disk before putting it in `JLabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. If you are loading the image from internet, `javax.swing.ImageIcon` constructor accepts URL as parameter which then you give the `ImageIcon` to `JLabel`.

In response to your clarification, yes you can still do that.

There are a few options, here are a couple:

1. You can still the same method above and use *"file://your/image/file"* as the URL to `ImageIcon`.
2. `ImageIcon` also accepts `byte[]` of image data. So you can do your regular file reading into `ByteArrayInputStream` and get `byte[]` out of that.

Comment: Updated, sorry very much for the misunderstood.

Comment: Tried your update, but I get this image: https://gyazo.com/dadb0bfab3426b65f2e04ddeda41c23f      My code: http://pastebin.com/riYtEypV

Comment: How big is your img.dat file? Are you sure it only contains 1 line? Because your code only read the first line of the file. Do you have the original img.jpg file? Can you read the jpg image file directly?

Comment: My img.dat file is quit big (plain text (HEX), 140kb). Of course it only contains 1 line. I do have the original img.jpg and I can load it successfully. Code updated: http://pastebin.com/J8zHLqtV

Comment: Okay, I found out that the problem was my img.dat file, it is corrupt. Sorry for making you loose your time. One last question, would this be possible with videos and audios?

Comment: Similar concept of reading file can be applied to video & audio, depend the target recipient. Although typical video or audio classes usually accept InputStream object for performance reason, so you do not load the whole video file to memory.